# Superslides update element on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm setting up the absolutely great Superslides by nicinabox.

What I would like to do, is to update some text on the page depending on what image is currently displayed.

How can I do this?

I am currently serving this page via Sinatra, and have converted Superslides into an erb file. When the page is initially loaded, a random s3 bucket is selected, and the images dynamically passed to the erb template.

Can I just pass say, a hash to the erb file, with the image pointer and the text I want to display?

Is there a way I can do this in ruby? Or is it more of a javascript thing.

Unfortunately I do not have any code yet, because i really do not know where to start.

Here is the URL to the project currently: http://pacific-brushlands-9242.herokuapp.com/
The text I would like to change is '@twitterhandle'.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and see how it compares to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Superslides allows you to add text with each slide. You do not have to "roll your own" solution. This text must be inside a div with a class of "container" which must be inside the "slides-container" UL tag.

The code to do this is below, this code is taking from index.erb and assumes that you have passed a hash, @images, to the erb view:

```
<ul class="slides-container">
  <% @images.each do |k, v| %>
  <li>
  <img src="<%= "#{k}" %>">
  <div class="container">
    <%= "#{v}" %>
  </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just adding some more detail, Key = pointer to image, Value = text to go along with image.